# Setting up a web server on ubuntu server 13.04 with user panel

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-server, lamp, ubuntu-13.04

I currently have Ubuntu Server installed to a VirtualBox image runnin on my main computer, I am wanting to use it for a web server with a user panel such as webmin (from my research i think this looked best).

What is best to install to the server once installed? 
Would people recommend L.A.M.P?

Does anyone maybe have an up to date guide on this at all, including making the server connectable via SSH outside the network (which ive also already installed to server, SSH that is).

My Webmin user panel is currently setup and working.

This servers mainly for testing but eventually I want to run a website/blog from there which will need sql, php, and probably some protection

I'm pretty new to servers so go easy on me, I feel I've came some length so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Server can be a choice, but if you want to have a long term running server, you should take its LTS version, which will allow you long term support.

As you are a begginner in Linux Web Servers, Ubuntu would be OK.

To my mind, I would prefer Debian (Ubuntu is based on Debian), well known as stable (long term support only) and free of any proprietary software or drivers.

LAMP is for : Linux Apache MySQL PHP, this is one of the most used. So yes it is recommended that you start with this (moreover, it is easy to setup).

The best practices for security is to never open any security issue. For the SSH, you should use an authentication method that doesn't allow password only (public key authentication).

Webmin is good for easy and simple tasks. As for your case, you don't need to manage many websites, so it won't be too limited. But anyway, with the time, you will learn that using command line will be much easier and faster.

Further security ?
You have many choices, such as using a reverse proxy, load balancers, clustering failover/failback, SAN storage... at any level (services, network, storage, systems...)

What else do you need ? A guide ? An easy one then, check out this one, I really like the website, as it is well updated for each server versions coming out, there are all the basic setups guides.

> http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_12.04&p=download

Comment: Thanks, I will install LAMP next then, I would of thought someone would of generated a guide with all the blogs around but not found one that cuts it, sourced all my info from a variety of sources so its been a difficult but informative process.
You have experience running a server from a virtualbox before? I am able to access my webmin user panel and ssh to the server via my network IP for it but how can I gain access outside of my network? What order is this usually done?
Will checkout that site tomorrow as in bed now and my blackberry won't display that site nicely at all lol